# How to create APIs for UserProfile with rest framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I  have created a UserProfile model with OneToOne relationship with User model.
The UserProfile model is shown below.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, unique=True, null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media", blank=True )
    current_location=  models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=False, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("created at", auto_now_add=True)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['created']:
            user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

    post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

The serializer class is shown below.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import UserProfile


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ( 'mobile_number',
          'current_location'
         ,'university','profile_image')
```

Iam using token authentication. How can I use the `ListCreateView`and other classes to implement the post, put ,get and delete method in the best way possible. I also need to validate these data before saving(like mobile_number length should be 10 and mandatory)

I tried to build a view as shown below.

```
from .models import UserProfile
from .serializers import UserProfileSerializer

class UserProfileView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    print(queryset)
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserProfile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=self.request.user)
        print(str(self.request.user.id)+"..."+str(profile))
        return serializer.save(userprofile=profile)
```

But it gives me error:

```
Got a `TypeError` when calling `UserProfile.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `UserProfile.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the UserProfileSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
```

how can I solve the problem.

The stack trace is shown below

```
Internal Server Error: /users/userprofile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 932, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 420, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 501, in __init__
    raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: UserProfile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'userprofile'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 242, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/home/vishnu/git_repos/Agora42core/users/views.py", line 23, in perform_create
    return serializer.save(userprofile=profile)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 213, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 951, in create
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Got a `TypeError` when calling `UserProfile.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `UserProfile.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the UserProfileSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
Original exception was:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 932, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 420, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/home/vishnu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 501, in __init__
    raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: UserProfile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'userprofile'
```

Comment: What's the specific issue your facing? There's nothing special about the `UserProfile`, it just works the same as any other model with DRF. What have you tried? You should not have `null=True, blank=True` on the `mobile_number` if it's mandatory. And start by adding validation on the Model itself, that's where it belongs in the first place.

Comment: This is too vague. What you have tried?

Comment: @JPG  I have edited the question.

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: Why are you using `ListCreateAPIView` if you're updating an existing profile? As its name indicates, a `ListCreateAPIView` is for creating multiple objects at once.

Comment: @dirkgroten I have added the stack trace

Comment: You're passing `userprofile=profile` into the serializer's `save()` method, but the serializer is for `UserProfile` which doesn't have a field `userprofile` and it's trying to pass that to the new `UserProfile` object it creates. Again, why are you using `ListCreateAPIView` if you're **updating an existing** user profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really **creating** a new `UserProfile` object, your `perform_create()` method should just pass the `user` into the serialiser's `save()` method:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    return serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

But if you already have a `UserProfile`, which looks like it's what your expecting since you're using `get_object_or_404`, then you should use a `UpdateAPIView` instead of a `ListCreateAPIView`:

```
class UserProfileView(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserProfile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

For PUT, PATCH, you need to define(override) **create** and **update**

Validation can be done at two levels. Both are shown below:

**At Serializer level,** 
it is just validate**_field_variable_name**

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ( 'mobile_number',
          'current_location'
         ,'university','profile_image')

    #For POST
    def create(self, validated_data):
        <your code,>

    #for PATCH
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        <your code,>

    #Validation
    def validate_mobile_number(self, cell_number):
         #Validate code here
```

More:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/

**Validation at Model level:**

You can also do this kind of validation at model level, like length of string etc.

Particular to mobile number, there are other modules which can do this unless you want special cases to handle.

from django.db import models
from phone_field import PhoneField

class UserProfile(models.Model):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
mobile_number = PhoneField(blank=True, unique=True, null=True)
```

https://pypi.org/project/django-phone-field/